# Recommend easy French shows for beginners

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire, apprentissage

I'm a native Urdu speaker with native level proficiency in English language. I am learning French these days. I'd like to know if there are some French movies or TV series with easy phrases through which I can pick up French.

Comment: In my opinion, for a beginner, shows for kids are the best. Any cartoon would be good. Also, dubbed movies are easier to understand than genuine French movies (slower pronunciation, less expressions).

Comment: Please recommend some French animated movies as well.

Answer (score 4):

I sometimes watch French quiz shows. Often the questions are shown as subtitles. So you learn something about contemporary French culture, vocabulary, pronunciation and formulating simple questions and answers. There are also quiz shows for teenagers and kids, as the comment by oli suggests.

Thanks to internet, you should be able to watch French TV at your location:

- http://schoener-fernsehen.com/
- http://www.tvprogramm24.com/tv-sender/

TF1, M6, France 1-4 you can watch over this site.

Ha, Wikipedia has a link for everything: [French game shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:French_game_shows).

On YouTube you will also find more kids stuff, also put "subtitles" in the search box

Comment: Most of the shows quoted on the Wikipedia EN page doesn't longer exists, but it's a great idea :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm French, I tought English for some years. Watching French movies would maybe be a bit too difficult at the beginning. But maybe you could at first try to watch a movie or TV series you know really well in French. If you feel it is too easy, then start watching a real French movie, first with English subtitles, and after with French ones.
I know I gave the same advice to my pupils when they wanted to improve their English or get a better pronunciation. When I learnt English, it is what I did and it really helped. I think this method can work both ways...

French is tricky so good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend BBC's Ma France module. It includes fun exercises to test your comprehension as well.
Specific advice for original poster: Mere khyaal shuru mein yeh zyaada phayedemand rahega. Baad main aap filmen subtitles ke saath dekh sakteen hain.

Comment: Can you please say what language the last two sentences are in and translate into English.

Comment: @Laure: “In my opinion, this would be more beneficial in the beginning. Later on you can progress to films with subtitles”/“Á mon avis, il serait plus utilé en commençant. Plutard, vous pouvez regarder les films avec sous-titres” :-)

Comment: @Laure: Hindi/Urdu